How to integrate $\int\frac{2x+7}{4+(1+x)^2}dx$ without splitting it up?
$$I=\int\frac{2x+7}{4+(1+x)^2}dx$$
$$I=2\int\frac{x}{4+(1+x)^2}dx+7\int\frac{dx}{4+(1+x)^2}$$
I know immediately the integral on the right $=\frac12\arctan\left(\frac u2 \right)$.
However, I solved the first integral in what I think is a rather inefficient way. This is where I expect I missed a shortcut, or perhaps am lacking knowledge of integral tables.
$$2\int\frac{x}{4+(1+x)^2}dx$$
letting $u=1+x$
$$2\int\frac{u-1}{2^2+u^2}du$$
I now split it into two integral yet again
$$2\int\frac{u}{2^2+u^2}du-2\int\frac{du}{2^2+u^2}$$
And we arrive at the following after consulting our integral table.
$$\ln(4+u^2)-\arctan\left(\frac u2 \right)$$
Combining everything I arrived at a solution (confirmed with Mathematica):
$$I=\ln(4+(1+x)^2)+\frac52\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{2} \right)$$
Once again, my question is how can this be solved in a more efficient manner? Solving this involved a painful amount of scratch work which I feel could've been avoided.

I don't see how you can ever get $\ln(\dots)+\arctan(\dots)$ without splitting it up into two integrals. I guess you can use partial fractions with complex roots if $(x+1)^2+4,$ but that is gonna be even less fun.

Just use $$\int \frac{2x + 7}{4 + (1 + x)^{2}} dx = \int \frac{2(1 + x)}{4 + (1 + x)^{2}} dx + 5 \int \frac{1}{4 + (1 + x)^{2}} dx$$ at the beginning.

As mentioned in the comments, one has
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2x + 7}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{2(x + 1)}{4 + ( x + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x + \int\frac{5}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
To start with, I recommend you to approach the first integral on the RHS as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2(x + 1)}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x + 1)^{2}}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}{u}}{4 + u} = \ln|4 + u| + C = \ln|5 + 2x + x^{2}| + A
\end{align*}
After so, the second integral on the RHS can be handled as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{5}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = 5\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x + 1)}{4 + (x + 1)^{2}} = 5\int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{4 + v^{2}} = \frac{5}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{v}{2}\right) = \frac{5}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{x + 1}{2}\right) + B
\end{align*}
As far as I know, this is the fastest way to calculate it.

Notice that the derivative of $4+(1+x)^2$ is $2+2x$.
So split the integrand accordingly to
$$\int \frac{2x+2}{1+(1+x)^2}dx+ \int \frac{5}{4+(1+x)^2}dx= \ln(1+(1+x)^2)+ \frac{1}{2}\arctan(\frac{x+1}{2})+C$$

This answer is not so different but this probably is the fastest way to solve this integral, $$I=\int\frac{2x+7}{4+(1+x)^2}dx=\int\frac{2(x+1)+5}{4+(1+x)^2}dx$$
$$I=\int\frac{2(x+1)+5}{4+(1+x)^2}dx= 2\int\frac{(x+1)}{4+(1+x)^2}dx+\int\frac{5}{4+(1+x)^2}dx$$
$$x+1=t\implies dx=dt$$
$$I=\int\frac{2t}{4+t^2}\,dt+\int\frac{5}{4+t^2}\,dt$$
$\frac{d}{dt}(t^2+4)=2t$, using $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx=\ln(|f(x)|)+c$ , $\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+c$, Notice
$$I=\ln(t^2+4)+\frac{5}{4}\tan^{-1}(t)+C$$
$$I=\ln(4+(x+1)^2)+\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)+C=\ln(x^2+2x+5)+\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)+C$$
